# I want to put the output of this print(d) function into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bioservices

I am working with the bioservices package in python and I want to take the output of this function and put it into a dataframe using pandas

```
from bioservices import UniProt
u = UniProt(verbose=False)
d = u.search("yourlist:M20211203F248CABF64506F29A91F8037F07B67D133A278O", frmt="tab", limit=5,
             columns="id, entry name")
print(d)
```

[this is the result I am getting, almost like a neat little table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EJqi.png)

The problem however is I cannot work with the data in this form and I want to put it into a dataframe using pandas

trying this code below does not work and it only returns the error "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called"

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Entry','Entry name'],
              data=d)
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you test `df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Entry','Entry name'],
              data=d.split())` ?

Comment: I tried it, I get this error now raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (13, 1), indices imply (13, 2)

Comment: Solution below should working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv`, after encapsulating your output in a `StringIO` (to present a file-like interface):

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = 'Entry\tEntry name\na\t1\nb\t2'
io_data = io.StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(io_data, sep='\t')
print(df)
```

The output is a dataframe:

```
  Entry  Entry name
0     a           1
1     b           2
```

Sample data:

```
from bioservices import UniProt
import io

u = UniProt(verbose=False)
d = u.search("yourlist:M20211203F248CABF64506F29A91F8037F07B67D133A278O", frmt="tab", limit=5,
             columns="id, entry name")
#print(d)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(d), sep='\t')
print(df)
    Entry   Entry name
0  Q8TAS1  UHMK1_HUMAN
1  P35916  VGFR3_HUMAN
2  Q96SB4  SRPK1_HUMAN
3  Q6P3W7  SCYL2_HUMAN
4  Q9UKI8   TLK1_HUMAN
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I simply substituted 'Entry\tEntry name\na\t1\nb\t2' with my variable d and I obtained a data frame just like you said. And if I have the option to create CSV files like you said that would help a lot, i have to look a bit more into it